# How to get back file from Docusign template using REST Api?

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

I can send file with templateid, get list of templates using REST api in Docusign api, now i want to get files from template using REST Api.
I can get list of templates in my account and can loop and get exact template id. From that i want to get back files using Rest api code. Pls help us to provide how to call rest api to get files from templatesid from Docusing api. Using Docusing dll, i can retrieve files, but i need to retrieve using Rest Api .

Here i paste code which download file from docusing Template using docusing dll.

```
Private Function DoWork(ByVal accessToken As String, ByVal basePath As String, ByVal accountId As String, ByVal envelopeId As String, ByVal documents As List(Of EnvelopeDocItem), ByVal docSelect As String) As FileStreamResult
    Dim config = New Configuration(New ApiClient(basePath))
    config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
    Dim envelopesApi As EnvelopesApi = New EnvelopesApi(config)
    Dim results As System.IO.Stream = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, docSelect)
    Dim docItem As EnvelopeDocItem = documents.FirstOrDefault(Function(d) docSelect.Equals(d.DocumentId))
    Dim docName As String = docItem.Name
    Dim hasPDFsuffix As Boolean = docName.ToUpper().EndsWith(".PDF")
    Dim pdfFile As Boolean = hasPDFsuffix
    Dim docType As String = docItem.Type

    If ("content".Equals(docType) OrElse "summary".Equals(docType)) AndAlso Not hasPDFsuffix Then
        docName += ".pdf"
        pdfFile = True
    End If

    If "zip".Equals(docType) Then
        docName += ".zip"
    End If

    Dim mimetype As String

    If pdfFile Then
        mimetype = "application/pdf"
    ElseIf "zip".Equals(docType) Then
        mimetype = "application/zip"
    Else
        mimetype = "application/octet-stream"
    End If
   
    Return File(results, mimetype, docName)
    
End Function
```

Regards and Thanks
Aravind

Comment: Actually I know a little about docusign, but "retrieve file from template" is not a clear enough description of your requirement, as I already indicated. So instead of saying "you should already know what I mean", please instead explain yourself more clearly as requested. Otherwise, we can't help you. If we had understood you perfectly, we wouldn't need to ask for clarification. Maybe also show us the code you did to work with the DLL, then we can try to understand the equivalent functionality through the API. Please help us to help you, instead of being critical of the helpers. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, at a guess, you want [this method](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/TemplateDocuments/get/) but I can't be sure from the vague description.

Comment: hi, i am new to docusign product, i cant find the code using api for retrive back files fromtemplate, so i cant show codes for api level.

Comment: Ok. So, does the last link I showed you provide the functionality you want? We can only guess, because you still haven't explained in any more detail what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I rolled back your edit as it made the existing comments and answers nonsensical. If you have a new problem, please ask a new question. You don't append to old, finished questions. That's not how this site works. Thanks.

Comment: hi, i cant ask new question any more, bcz my account is banned from asking question, when i read the policy, they mention to update the existing question and description in order to remove ban, so i change description which i get banned question. Thanks

Comment: Well, sorry to hear that, but that's not everyone else's problem. It's not a reason to deface an older question, or try to sneak in a new question under an old heading. You have to wait for your account to be unblocked - normally it's a temporary restriction. Of course as the policy says, you can help this by modifying earlier questions...but your edit completely altered the nature of the question to talk about a different problem, whereas what you've been asked to do really is simply clarify the existing question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@aravindb you can use this endpoint: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/TemplateDocuments/get/. As well there are 31 examples in 6 languages at https://github.com/docusign where you can see how to download documents

Comment: hi, above i updated description which get back file using Rest Api, but when i  convert to bytes i get an error.For download file i pass templateid and documentid as well as.